# When to flush Pyserial buffers?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am working with Pyserial and have a question regarding best practices surrounding flushing the input and output buffers. Currently I reset the output buffer before sending a command and reset the input before reading the reply. It seems I occasionally miss the start of a reply so I am considering modifying my program to reset the input buffer before I send my command. I am also considering linking my send and receive functions so that the send always calls the receive and hopefully tightens up the loop.

```
    def send_cmd(self, cmd_to_send):
        self.ser.reset_output_buffer()
        self.ser.write(cmd_to_send)

    def receive_cmd(self):
        self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
        # Read logic below
```

Considering transitioning to something like this

```
    def send_cmd(self, cmd_to_send):
        self.ser.reset_output_buffer()
        self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
        self.ser.write(cmd_to_send)
        self.receive_cmd()

    def receive_cmd(self):
        # Read logic below
```

Comment: Clarify your terminology.  *"Flush"* has been used to mean either "discard" or "wait for completion" depending on the API.  If  termios and/or USB are involved, then the numerous intermediate buffers will hinder any *"tighting up the loop"*.

Comment: I will edit my post - by flush I meant reset_input/output_buffer. I am using a USB/RS232 adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post gets decent traffic so I just want to let everyone know I never found the answer to this question. I tried a variety of configurations but ultimately flushing seems to rely more on the hardware itself than the software. I did end up transitioning to the code I mentioned and it seemed to help, albeit slightly. So I would recommend something like this:

```
def send_cmd(self, cmd_to_send):
    self.ser.reset_output_buffer()
    self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
    self.ser.write(cmd_to_send)
    self.receive_cmd()

def receive_cmd(self):
    # Read logic below
```

If anyone can supply a better answer, I would still appreciate it :)

Edit: I also was reading bytes individually, as I needed to. You may have more success using readlines() as Eduardo mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the port configuration, the key `timeout` let you wait some time in each communication with the port.

I usually  use this parameter to prevent problems with the port buffer. Try this and maybe it is unnecessary to flush.

Comment: How does the timeout value actually work? (I.e. once I write a command does the port start listening for x seconds?) I currently have mine set to 1s but I am reading each byte individually until I find the escape character so does this still affect me? (I don't use readline())

Comment: I undestand that 'timeout', "wait" that amount of time before atempt to interact with any devices one more time. I ussually read a termometer with 0.5 s of timeout, I've never find any problem with buffer. By the way, I use readlines()

Answer (score -1):

```
def send_cmd(self, cmd_to_send):
    self.ser.reset_output_buffer()
    self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
    self.ser.time.sleep(0.1)
    self.ser.write(cmd_to_send)
    self.ser.time.sleep(0.1)
    self.receive_cmd()

def receive_cmd(self):
    # Read logic below
```

Comment: This is the same answer as mine except with sleeps. Is the sleep time arbitrary or do you have a reason for `0.1`? I recall experimenting with the sleep time and not noticing a difference.

Comment: This answer has no context to it and no reason for the additional sleeps. I found only a sleep is needed after opening the compport, maybe do to initialization? Either way this answer is incorrect.